# Filtering elements from a string input

Tags: python, string, list, return

The following string is given:

```
mystring = "animals.dog > 12 and type.type_id=105 and colors.name='yellow'"
```

I would like to return from this string the following elements.

```
table1 = animals
element1 = dog 
operator1= greater

table2 = type 
element2 = type_id
operator2= equal

table3 = colors
element3 = name
operator3 = equal
```

I am only interested in the first 3 parts, namely table.element operator (e.g. animals.dog>)

Unfortunately, I already fail with the conversion of the sentence into a list

I have currently tried the following things, but with this approach, the operators are not read along.

```
import re 
mystring = "animals.dog > 12 and type.type_id=105 and colors.name='yellow'"
wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  mystring).split()
```

I'd be very happy if you could help me with that.
Best regards

Comment: Write a small parser.

Comment: If that's python code, use `ast.parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that works for this example:

```
out = re.findall("([^\W]+)\.([^\W]+)\W*([<>=])", mystring)
```

output:

```
[('animals', 'dog', '>'), ('type', 'type_id', '='), ('colors', 'name', '=')]
```

But it would not support operators like `>=` or `<=`. If you need them you need to specify them in the regex.

Having output list, you can iterate over it like so:

```
for table, element, operator in out:
    ...
```